# How to convert xsd's library (more than one xsd) to ecore (EMF)

Tags: xsd, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

How to convert xsd's library (more than one xsd) to ecore (EMF)

During the XML Schema import, when i browse the file system for Model URI, 
Eclipse gives me option to select one xsd at a time,
What if i have multiple XSD's

Answer (score 0):

In Juno you are able to select more than one xsd in the EMF Project Wizard, when browsing the workspace. So if the behavior is different in File system browser, than you should create a project containing the xsds in your workspace first.